# Sublime TextのMacrosを使用して正規表現で文字を置換したい

Tags: sublimetext

正規表現で文字列を置換するマクロを
Sublime TextのTools -> Macros -> Users から
実行したいのですが文字列を置換するマクロの書き方がわかりません。

例えば下記の[^a] -> b のような置換をしたい場合は
どうすればよいのでしょうか？

apple
banana
↓
bpple
banana

Answer (score 2):

本家SOにもいくつか質問がありましたが、標準だと検索／置換は記録できないみたいです。
[RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace)というプラグインを入れると良いみたいですね。

[How do I record and run multiple find/replace with Sublime Text 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/605861/how-do-i-record-and-run-multiple-find-replace-with-sublime-text-2)
[Batch find and replace for Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656560/batch-find-and-replace-for-sublime-text-2)

ちなみにマクロで利用できるコマンドは下記参照とのこと。
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございました。
何度検索しても見つからなかったのですが
やはりマクロだけではできないのですね。

あとマクロのコマンドのドキュメントは公式サイトに存在していたのですね。
Supportなどのページを見てもコマンドのドキュメントのリンクがなかったので
存在しないものだと思っていました。
これでマクロで「できること」と「できないこと」がより明確になりそうです。